# Is Django Channel Appropriate implementing Optimistic Chat application like telegram or whatsapp?

Tags: python, sockets, chat, django-channels

I had implemented a real-time chat application web service which gives services to the web and mobile client. I found that channel makes separate sockets for every user and bind them in groups and rooms in Redis handling where a specific socket message should be sent.

So in this case, for example, the mobile platform has to save which sockets belong to which rooms and groups and in every message sending from the server, the mobile platform has to check what room this message belongs and send it on. think big like telegram and WhatsApp. it seems to me that it's not appropriate client saves multiple sockets for every user communicating with one server. Am i right??

Also in cases like WhatsApp(large scale applications) servers have sockets for every user in every room if they choose the Django channel. it makes a lot and lots of ports busy on the server.

I have experience implementing socket implementation using Redis, SocketIo, Laravel to. using these tools, I was free to use few sockets for sending all kinds of notifications to users using few socket ports. it was seemed lighter than Django channel.

With these kinds of thinkings, I have doubt to continue using Django channel in my project, and I am a little worried about when it deploys in large scales.

Should I be worried??